# What is $e^{2 \pi i \alpha}?$

Tags: analysis

I'm having a huge lapsus. Let $\alpha \in [0,1]$. From one point of view we have

$e^{2 \pi i \alpha} = (e^{2 \pi i})^{\alpha} = 1$

But I could also write

$e^{2 \pi i \alpha} = \cos(2 \pi \alpha) + i\sin(2 \pi \alpha) \neq 1$

What's wrong? I feel like i'm missing something REALLY obvius.

Comment: Take $\alpha=\frac{1}{3}$. Then the first formula is wrong - why? What are the values of $1^{1/3}$? How many third roots of $1$ are there?

Comment: Three of course.. i got your point. Root funciton is a "polifunction". Thanks, I completely forgot about that

Comment: What if $\alpha$ is irrational?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your argument.

According to the Euler's formula, we have $$e^{i \theta}=\cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta)$$

Thus $$e^{2\pi i\alpha } = \cos(2\pi\alpha) + i \sin(2\pi\alpha)$$

The power rule $$e^{xy}=(e^x)^y$$ does not hold for complex numbers.

For example  $$e^{2\pi i\alpha}\neq 1$$.